# [WRITING IN TIFF FILE FORMAT]: Error when writing multichannel numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy-ndarray, tiff

My goal is to **write multichannel image data in .tiff format**. As shown in the code below, first I produce a random numpy array of size 1000x1000 and 6 channels with values from 0 to 100. After this, I try to use the TiffWriter() function from the tiffile package in order to write the random array into a .tiff image in disk.

```
    import tiffile as  tf
    import numpy as np 
    img = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 1000, 6))
    tf.TiffWriter(img, "img.tiff")
```

TiffWriter gives me the following error:

> tf.TiffWriter(img, "img.tiff")
> TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

**Does anyone know what I am coding wrong when trying to save multichannel data in a TIFF file?**

Comment: Try `tifffile.imwrite("img.tiff", img)`.

Comment: @cgohlke exchanging the arguments doesn't work, gives the same error.

Comment: Use `imwrite`, not `TiffWriter`.